# Create a tree using XML in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, tree, smartgwt

I have an XML in the format :

```
<RootNode name="Tree">
    <ChildNode name="ChildNode1">
        <LeafNode name="Leaf">Leaf1</LeafNode>
        <LeafNode>Leaf2</LeafNode>
        <ChildNode name="ChildNode1.1">
            <LeafNode>Leaf1.1</LeafNode>
            <LeafNode>Leaf1.2</LeafNode>
            <LeafNode>Leaf1.3</LeafNode>
        </ChildNode>
    </ChildNode>
    <ChildNode name="ChildNode2">
        <LeafNode>Leaf3</LeafNode>
        <LeafNode>Leaf3</LeafNode>
    </ChildNode>
    <ChildNode name="ChildNode3">
    </ChildNode>
</RootNode>
```

How do i convert it to a tree using SmartGWT?

Comment: Have you seen the example provided by SmartGwt regarding TreeGrid here [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_miller_columns)?

Comment: Yes..I have seen the example but i am not able to manipulate it..please do help to get the format as above..

Comment: Is the provided XML actual data you have to parse, or a construct from you to show us as a paradigm for the data you want to parse? I am asking this because it doesn't seem very correct to me. Maybe you want to refine it to help us to help you ...

Comment: It approximately is the same the data i want to display in the tree. And i cannot modify the XML either as it is in the requirements. Is it possible or not cause i don't think it will be?? If you could give me the suggestions as to how do you think i need to modify even that would be a great help.

Comment: If you can't modify the XML schema of the data, then you might want to  have a look [link](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=4814&highlight=gwt-rpc). There you will find ideas on how to override the methods the datasource uses internally to parse your data and then do the parsing, according to your needs. You do not have to use GWT-RPC. Even a RequestBuilder can be used. Otherwise if you do not want to look in such a complex solution, you should try to convince the data provider to follow a schema closer to the SmartGWT's example (i.e. the link I provided at first comment).

Comment: Hey..i am trying to change the XML as per the one used in example. But still not able to achieve it as there is a childnode within a childnode node. Could you please suggest as to how can i achieve it.

Comment: Something like the following:  
   <ChildNode>
   <Name>ChildNode1</Name>
   <ReportsTo>0</ReportsTo>
   <LeafNode>Leaf2</LeafNode>
   </ChildNode>
   
   <ChildNode>
   <Name>ChildNode1.1</Name>
   <ReportsTo>ChildNode1</ReportsTo>
   <LeafNode>Leaf1.1</LeafNode>
   <LeafNode>Leaf1.2</LeafNode>
   <LeafNode>Leaf1.3</LeafNode>
   </ChildNode>
   
   <ChildNode>
   <Name>ChildNode2</Name>
   <ReportsTo>0</ReportsTo>
   <LeafNode>Leaf3</LeafNode>
   <LeafNode>Leaf3</LeafNode>
   </ChildNode>
  
Even the LeafNodes can be simpler ChildNones that ReportsTo to the ChildNode needed.